# Performing mobile search on an android device using python

Tags: android, python

How might I go about performing automated mobile search using python?

I have a program exploiting the Microsoft Rewards program, but currently I'm limited to desktop search. The bot performs random searches via bing for various accounts to gain points, later redeemed for voucher codes.

My intention is to do the same for mobile.

I appreciate this is quite a general question, but despite my best efforts, I can't find even a starting point.

Comment: You want to run Python on android? You can't do that in a reasonable way.

Comment: [List of ways to do it](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Android) - Should really use a search engine. And I don't think you're exploiting something that is intended to be used? If you're talking about scraping a website using Android? Then I suggest you use a browser in "Desktop mode". Your question is confusing and I vote to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done via a desktop through a browser mobile device simulation.

Chrome browser: More tools -> developer tools -> toggle device toolbar.

This can also be done via hotkeys and hence suitable for automation. Now have the program perform searches using the same desktop search protocol; searches will be performed as if they're from a mobile device.

Others browsers have this capability.